# Linking SCSS stylesheet to HTML

Tags: html, css, sass

Building a Flask project for a simple login screen project I plan to expand on, but here I am stuck on what I would have guessed would have been simple.

Why is my html below not updating to be styled by my login.css?
Here is a snippet up until the link relation:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=devilce-width, intial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/webapp/templates/login.css">
    </head>
```

It is inside of the same folder, but to make it what I believe to be fool-proof I specifically ran it through the full folder directory.

I have the .scss, the .cssmap from the compiler, and the output login.css in the same folder as the .html as well.

I've downloaded SASS, ran a Live Sass Compiler through VSCode, and now it's compiled to a .css

"What do"?

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: I'm unsure why my login.html is not updating when being presented with the reference stylesheet. I've compiled it from Scss to css and it still does not change.

Comment: browsers often cache the css so you often need to flush caches to get the new css to pick up (F5 usually works - or go to the settings and clear caches)

Comment: Yes, tried that. I did prebuild it in codepen and exported. As a follow up I tried to use a different stylesheet I had but that did not work either.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure exactly the specifics, but from my understanding using {{ url_for--}} worked.
(If someone can follow up with an explanation that would be beautiful.)

Noticed when scanning examples from [PythonHow](https://pythonhow.com/python-tutorial/flask/Adding-CSS-styling-to-your-website/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intial-scale=1">
    <title>Flask App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css')}}">
</head>
```